# Where does fmt:message get the locale from?

Tags: jstl

I need to know how the fmt:message tag of the JSTL gets the locale from. i dont want to use fmt:setLocale. I want to customize the locale resolver that fmt:message uses. I know implementing the Spring's LocaleResolver works for spring message source. Is there anything similar for the fmt:message tag?

Thanks in Advance.